# {% for top in topwear.brand %} is not executing

Tags: python, html, django

I want to list the items by brand so user can choose according to the brand of the product in the sidebar but somehow it is not happenning

**views.py**

```
     class home(View):
        def get (self,request):
            products=Product.objects.all()
            topwear=Product.objects.filter(Category='TW')
            bottomwear=Product.objects.filter(Category='BW')
            context={'topwear':topwear,'bottomwear':bottomwear,'products':products}
            return render(request,'store/index.html',context)
```

**models.py**

```
     class Product(models.Model):
      category=[
        ('TW','Top Wear'),
        ('BW','Bottom Wear'),
        ('Shoes','Shoes'),
        ('mobile','mobile'),
        ('Laptop','Laptop')
      ]
      title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
      selling_price=models.FloatField()
      discounted_price=models.FloatField()
      description=models.TextField()
      brand=models.CharField(max_length=100)
      Category=models.CharField(choices=category,max_length=10)
      product_image=models.ImageField(upload_to='productimg')
   
      def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Bottom wear and mobile section is showing but not topwear section.
**index.html**
`your text`

```
     <div class="dropdown-menu position-absolute bg-secondary border-0 rounded-0 w-100 m-0">
                                {% for top in topwear.brand %}
                                <a href="{% url 'searchproduct' top %}" class="dropdown-item">Top Wear</a>
                                {% endfor %}
                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Bottom Wear</a>
                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">Mobile</a>
                            </div>
```

Everything else is running file .Just top wear section is not showing in browser. Is this syntax not correct?

Help will be appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
{% for top in topwear.brand %}
   <a href="{% url 'searchproduct' top %}" class="dropdown-item">Top Wear</a>
{% endfor %}
```

try this:

```
{% for top in topwear %}
  <a href="{% url 'searchproduct' top.brand %}" class="dropdown-item">Top Wear</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried that but it executes for the no of topwear not by top's brand .If i have 5 topwear but of two brands then i want to exceute that code for two times but if i write suggested by you it executes 5 times

Comment: write your orm query here only {% url 'searchproduct' write query here how you want %}